# How to use a custom view in layout xml

Tags: android, xml

I have made a custom view that I'm setting inside the onCreate() method in the Main Activity.

Like this:

```
compassView = new CompassView(this);
setContentView(compassView);
```

My question is. How do I reference the view in xml, so I can put it inside a linearlayout together with other controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `CompassView` is a class which is placed in the Package called ,

**com.android.sample**

Create a XML like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <com.android.sample.CompassView 
       android:id="@+id/compassview"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

      />
</LinearLayout>
```

And now as usual, `setContentView(R.layout.xmlname);` in your `onCreate()`.

And `compassView = (CompassView)findViewbyId(R.id.compassview);`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very nice explaination :)

Answer (score 0):

setContentView("here put your xml layout")

In .xml layout just simple add ur View:

```
<com.example.widget.CompassView
            android:id="@+id/..."
            style="@style/..." >
    </com.example.widget.CompassView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add your custom view In your xml file, something like this:

```
<yourpackagename.yourCustomViewClass
        android:id="@+id/myCustomView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

After this, you can access this view through its id, like you would have done for any other View

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must override any constructor of your superclass. If you don't do that you will get a run time error and you activity will never be opened. Then you should use the fully qualified class name like this:

```
<your_package_name.your_class_name
   android:id="@+id/mycompass"
   your attributes here
   ...
 />
```

Comment: @thilemann In particolar be sure to Override the constructor with Context and AttributeSet parameters. Then rate my answer please.